# ng-bind-html renders data as HTML but ignores children elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I'm working on this function that generates HTML based on user input and I can render it as proper HTML inside a list item (instead of a string version) using ng-bind-as-html.

The only problem is that it doesn't render the span tag that is also a child element in the li tag. I'm an Angular n00b and could use any insight ya got.

The code below allows me to have my functions output as proper HTML, which is nice, but I need that span tag to show up as it allows my user to copy the contents of the text.

Basically, I can either rewrite without ng-bind-html and have the span render appropriately, or I can have my HTML output render and not get the span tag. I'm stuck with one or the other and not both... and I want both. Classic.

Thanks for your help!

```
<li 
class="entry"
ng-repeat="entry in output track by $index"
ng-mouseenter="onEnter()"
ng-bind-html="entry">
  {{entry}}
  <span 
    class="copy"
    ng-click="copyData(entry)" 
    ng-mouseenter="onEnter()">
    {{message}}
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Haven't seen the below answer still?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `directive` to achieve this with `transclude` and `ng-transclude` as below.

[Documentation for ng-transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'You are welcome!';
  $scope.output = ['<h1>Hello user</h1>'];
}]);

app.directive('bindHtml', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span><span ng-bind-html="html"></span><span ng-transclude></span></span>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtml));
    }
  };
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
<li 
class="entry"
ng-repeat="entry in output track by $index"
ng-mouseenter="onEnter()"
bind-html="entry">
  <span 
    class="copy"
    ng-click="copyData(entry)" 
    ng-mouseenter="onEnter()">
    {{message}}
  </span>
</li>
</div>
```